# Why does all.equal(1,2,3) return TRUE

Tags: r

I tried `all.equal(1,2)` and it returned a mean difference of 1.

Why does `all.equal(1,2,3)` show `TRUE`?

Is it because if it is supplied more than two variables it runs is.numeric() on its different elements to check their type instead of numerical differences?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because 1 is equal to 2 within a tolerance of 3. From the docs:

```
  target: R object.

 current: other R object, to be compared with ‘target’.

     ...: Further arguments for different methods, notably the
          following two, for numerical comparison:

tolerance: numeric >= 0.  Differences smaller than ‘tolerance’ are not
          reported.  The default value is close to ‘1.5e-8’.
```

Your 3 is the third argument, and so becomes the tolerance.

Comment: `all.equal(2+2, 5, 1)` -- statistician joke